# Reference dynamically generated id in Angular2 template

Tags: angular

I'm using ngSemantic and I don't know how I can reference a dynamically generated ID.

I have several panels with a sidebar.
To open the sidebar I need to declare

```
 (click)="sidebarId.show()"
```

I set the id of the sidebar in this way:

```
<sm-sidebar id="{{panelId}}-sidebar"></sm-sidebar>
```

I would need to call something like

```
(click)="{{panelId}}-sidebar.show()"
```

but this doesn't work since I receive this error:

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in
>   [{{panelId}}-sidebar.show()] in PanelComponent@13:31

Comment: So you have `{{panelId}}-sidebar` objects declared in your component so that you can call their `show` method?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use ngSemantic.
But id is not a instance, you can't use id to call any method
Instead, you should use # to obtain the component instance, thus you can call the instance.method

```
    <h4 class="ui header">Demo</h4>
<sm-button class="positive icon" icon="sidebar" (click)="invertedSidebar.show({transition: 'overlay'})">
Lunch left sidebar</sm-button> 
<sm-sidebar class="left vertical inverted sidebar labeled icon menu" #invertedSidebar>        
    <a class="item">
        <i class="home icon"></i>
        Home
    </a>
    <a class="item">
        <i class="block layout icon"></i>
        Topics
    </a>
    <a class="item">
        <i class="smile icon"></i>
        Friends
    </a>
</sm-sidebar>
```

https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ngSemantic/blob/456c4198860d2d3ce49e975753bd79fef6881fca/demo/app/components/elements/sidebar.ts

For more complex case, you can pass the id to a custom function to obtain corresponding component instance by using @ViewChildren decorator
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I have multiple sidebar, so i need to declare a dynamic id for each component instance. Following your example, I can't declare #invertedSidebar, but I would declare #sidebar-timestamp and I don't know how to obtain it

Comment: A click event can have a $event parameter, it will also contain the instance (click)="openSiderbar($event)" . Ref https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

Answer (score 0):

If your component is within an *ngFor loop, you could use the index as the unique id. Otherwise, you could initialize a date object when the component is instantiated and use the timestamp as the unique ID as each date object.

Comment: Yes, I already add an unique ID to my element, but I dont know how i can reference it inside (click)

Comment: Gotcha... I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dynamic names then you would use bracket notation:

```javascript
(click)="this[panelId + '-sidebar'].show()"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using eval() to evaluate the expression...

```
(click)="show(panelId)"


function show(panelId) {
    eval(panelId + '-sidebar.show()');
}
```